# updating date from a mat-input with material module

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have this code

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6h1wvj

and i would like that the user can update de value of the date using the calendar and the imput, actualy we can update with the calendar but i got error with the mat-input with the var type date that im using.

im trying to use

```
(change)="onChangeEvent($event)"
```

but i receive null when accessing to $event.value

i what something similar to this
https://stackblitz.com/angular/odrmqdenkrv?file=app%2Fdatepicker-events-example.html
in which you can update with the calendar and the input with only valid dates and get a null if date is invalid but with my configuration of month year

Comment: Hmmm.. What are you trying to get with `onChangeEvent`?

Comment: The value changed from the mat-input to reasign to date var

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `(change)` use `(dateInput)` and `(dateChange)`, just like in the example you provided, and passe `$event` only. Also in your `MY_FORMATS` make sure your `parse: { dateInput:` is the same format as the one you `display: { dateInput:`.

So:

```
parse: {
    dateInput: 'MMMM/YYYY',
},
```

If you don't have them similar, that means the user inputs date in a certain format but the display expect another format, so you'd need to modify the user input in your `onChangeEvent` to fit the display format.

I'll assume you just want the user to stick with the displayed format so just have them similar in your `MY_FORMATS`

For the changes to reflect I'd also use `[(ngModel)]` instead of value. Or keep `[value]` but use another value to assign in `onChangeEvent` and display in your template

[Here's a working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6h1wvj-uj2t5n?file=app/datepicker-views-selection-example.ts)

Let me know if that helps :)